# Invalid Date using moment.js and Pikaday

Tags: javascript, datepicker, momentjs, pikaday

Im trying to pass a user selected date using Pikaday into a variable to be processed in a form using the following javascript, but my page is returning "Invalid Date".

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="pikaday.js"></script>

<script>
var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker'), 
  firstDay: 1,
  minDate: moment().add({days: 20}).toDate(),
  disableDayFn: function(date){// Disable Monday 
    return date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6;
  },
  onSelect: function(date) {
    field.value = moment(picker.toString()).format("MM/DD/YY");
  }
});

var selecteddate =  moment(picker.toString()).format("MM/DD/YY");
</script>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You can use [`picker.getMoment()`](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#get-and-set-date) instead of `moment(picker.toString())`

Comment: this for the first time produces an output! Though i believe its missing formatting? by selecting 2016-10-12 the output is 1473866229647 , any ideas ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a new option "format" and change "onSelect":

Example

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div>

        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">

    </div>

<script>
var picker = new Pikaday({
  field: document.getElementById('datepicker'), 
  firstDay: 1,
  format:'MM/DD/YY',
  minDate: moment().add({days: 20}).toDate(),
  disableDayFn: function(date){// Disable Monday 
    return date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6;
  },
  onSelect: function(date) {
   this._o.field.value =this.getMoment().format("MM/DD/YY");
  document.getElementById('datepicker2').value = picker.toString("MM/DD/YY");
  }
});

var selecteddate =  moment(picker.toString()).format("MM/DD/YY");
</script>
</body>

</html>
```